# How to "change" immutable objects effectively?

Tags: c#, immutability

Is there any clever design pattern or sort of generic method for "modification" of immutable objects?

Background:
Let's have set of different (not having common `base`) immutable objects, each having different set of `{get; private set;}` properties and one public constructor (accepting set of property values). These objects are and should remain immutable, but from time to time, in sort of special mode, their values are required to "change".

Such kind of modification means just creation of new object having the same values as the original one except the updated properties (like `o = new c(o.a, updateB, updateC, o.d, ...)`).

I can imagine calling the constructors in place, or defining an (e.g. extension) method returning new instance, accepting some parameters to identify the updated property/ies and modifying it/them via reflection, but everything seems to be very specific and not elegant to be used system wide for "any" immutable. I like the way `linq` handles e.g. the `IEnumerable`s and the chain you can produce and completely re-transform the input collection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example of something similar I'm aware of is Roslyn, Microsoft's current C# compiler, which uses immutable data structures extensively. The syntax tree classes have convenience methods for every property for returning a new instance with just one property changed, e.g.

```
var cu = Syntax.CompilationUnit()
            .AddMembers(
                Syntax.NamespaceDeclaration(Syntax.IdentifierName("ACO"))
                        .AddMembers(
                        Syntax.ClassDeclaration("MainForm")
                            .AddBaseListTypes(Syntax.ParseTypeName("System.Windows.Forms.Form"))
                            .WithModifiers(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
                            .AddMembers(
                                Syntax.PropertyDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName("System.Windows.Forms.Timer"), "Ticker")
                                        .AddAccessorListAccessors(
                                        Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration).WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
                                        Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration).WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))),
                                Syntax.MethodDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName("void"), "Main")
                                        .AddModifiers(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
                                        .AddAttributes(Syntax.AttributeDeclaration().AddAttributes(Syntax.Attribute(Syntax.IdentifierName("STAThread"))))
                                        .WithBody(Syntax.Block())
                                )
                        )
                );
```

or in your case:

```
o = o.WithB(updateB).WithC(updateC);
```

which I think reads quite nicely for the intended use case (updating only a few properties while keeping everything else the same). It especially beats the »always have to call the ctor« approach when there are *many* properties.

In Roslyn that's all auto-generated, I think. You can probably do something similar with T4, if warranted.

Comment: Thanks for the T4 note, wasn't aware of this tool!

Comment: The source will read horrible when using it, but at least it's integrated nicely with Visual Studio. I have used other approaches for auto-generated code as well, which require either a separate build step or manual rebuild of the source file after you change the generating script.